# how to call function in php outside from mysite

Tags: php, url

I want to call a php function from my other site...it is possible
php file is look like this on my server - daplonline.in/short.php

```
<?php
function writeMsg() {
  echo "Hello world!";
}
?>
```

And i want to call this function from my other site is it possible ?

```
<?php
    include("http://daplonline.in/short.php"); //it is 777
    writeMsg();
?>
```

Comment: have you got any error while processing this script??

Comment: Impossible:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101327/using-includes-cross-domain-that-contain-php-code-failing

Comment: This is not possible no... Even if this site was on the same production server u would get a base_restriction on this include

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1158392/3000179

Comment: possible duplicate of [including a remote file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158348/including-a-remote-file-in-php)

Comment: Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\aff\ss.php on line 2


Warning: include(http://daplonline.in/short.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\aff\ss.php on line 2
.

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://daplonline.in/short.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\aff\ss.php on line 2

Comment: got 3 error in my file

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called RMI in Java. But as far as I know there's nothing in PHP which can do "Remote Method Invocations". So I would say it's not possible.

But you could write a script which calls the right function based on the URI of the request.

So let's say over a `$_GET` paramter:

> http://daplonline.in/rmi.php?method=short.writeMessage

Then in your `rmi.php` you have to call the right function based on the `method` paramter.

```
<?php

list($scriptName, $methodName) = explode('.', $_GET['method']);

require $scriptName . '.php';

echo serialize(call_user_func($methodName));
```

To abstract it quick and dirty. You than can `unserialize()` the response of the `rmi.php` and get the returned data.

Comment: [It is there in PHP, but not suggested due to secirty reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158348/including-a-remote-file-in-php) :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It's a huge security risk though.

> [**`allow_url_include`**](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) *boolean*
>
> This option allows the use of URL-aware fopen wrappers with the following functions: include, include_once, require, require_once.

```
ini_set('allow_url_include', 1);
```

Further reading: [including a remote file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158348/including-a-remote-file-in-php/1158392#1158392)

Comment: It should be mentioned that for URL-including over HTTP, the targetted server must not interpret the requested script, but return it as-is.

Comment: where shout i ste ?? ini_set('allow_url_include', 1);

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to the file using `CURL`, and specify a parameter.

The file could check that parameter and call a particular function.

It's not exactly what you want, but it should work. It's better to make this like an API, instead of including external PHP files and then calling the functions from them. You could add more security this way, like accepting connections only from certain URLs.

`short.php` will contain something like

```
<?php
function writeMsg() {
    echo "Hello world!";
}
writeMsg();
?>
```

The file from the other server can contain

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://daplonline.in/short.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

`$result` will be the output of the `short.php` script

Comment: i want to call function writeMsg() from my other site only

Comment: then maybe using the `allow_url_include` approach would be better. But if `writeMsg()` does not take any parameters, and you want to call only this function, you can use CURL too. That external file will call the function and can return the output. So you just display it, on the main site's page.

Comment: allow_url_include is safe ??

Comment: As the other people were saying, enabling allow_url_include means people will be able to include the php file from that server, so it is not safe. CURL is normally used for this type of requests

Comment: so can i create API ? for call the function ?

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61990/discussion-between-cornelb-and-user3705511).

Comment: maybe you can play a bit with the curl settings. I added something in the answer